# AADSTS54005: OAuth2 Authorization code was already redeemed, please retry with a new valid code or use an existing refresh token

Tags: xamarin.forms, office365, adal

xamarin forms with office 365 authentification 
the authentification works fine but lately i receive this error message :

AADSTS54005: OAuth2 Authorization code was already redeemed, please retry with a new valid code or use an existing refresh token.

with some research i find that i need to refresh the token. -->

https://support.workspace365.net/hc/en-us/articles/360010259114--RESOLVED-Technical-issue-Workspace-365
the question is how to refresh the token can anyone guide me.

Thank you

This my code :

```
    public async Task<AuthenticationResult> Authenticate(string authority, string resource, string clientId, string returnUri)
    {
        AuthenticationResult authResult = null;
        try
        {
            var authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority);
            if (authContext.TokenCache.ReadItems().Any())
                authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authContext.TokenCache.ReadItems().First().Authority);
            var uri = new Uri(returnUri);
            PlatformParameters platformParams = null;
```

android

```
            platformParams = new PlatformParameters((Android.App.Activity)Forms.Context);
```

ios

```
            Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
            {
                UIViewController controller = new UIViewController();
                controller = UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow.RootViewController;
                platformParams = new PlatformParameters(controller);
            });


            UserDialogs.Instance.HideLoading();
```

Authresult need to return the token so i can use it from office 365 authentification but instead i receive the message AADSTS54005: OAuth2 Authorization...

```
            authResult = await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(resource, clientId, uri, platformParams);
            authContext.TokenCache.Clear();

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Execption : " + e.Message);
        }

        return authResult;
    }
```

any help will be appreciated Thank you

Comment: Maybe this article can be helpful.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow#refresh-the-access-token @Soufiane BENHADDOU Or you can Change the token lifetime to have a try.